# Python re.sub() not working as expected

Tags: python

I would like to write a conditional replace using `re.sub()`. Basically, I want to enclose a word in backticks(`) if it is found in the `h_kw` set. Can you please advise what I am doing wrong as it always prints without the backtick even though the word is present in the set.

```
>>>h_kw = set('COLLECTION','JOIN')
>>> def kw_correction(c_name,kw=h_kw):
...     if c_name.upper() in kw:
...         return "`"+c_name+"`"
...     else:
...         return c_name
...
>>>line = "select v['collection'] as test"
>>>test = re.sub(r"(v\[')(.*)('\])", kw_correction(r'\2'), line.rstrip())
>>> print (test)
select collection as test
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that you are passing `\2` as a string into kw_correction, not `collection` and then returning `\2` to be parsed by the regex engine, you can see as below:

```
>>> def kw_correction(c_name,kw=h_kw):
     print(kw,c_name)
     if c_name.upper() in kw:
         return "`"+c_name+"`"
     else:
         return c_name


>>> re.sub(r"(v\[')(.*)('\])", kw_correction(r'\2'), line.rstrip())
{'JOIN', 'COLLECTION'} \2
'select collection as test'
```

you need to pass the actual match into the function.

```
>>> re.sub(r"(v\[')(.*)('\])", kw_correction(re.search(r"(v\[')(.*)('\])",line.rstrip()).group(2)), line.rstrip())
{'JOIN', 'COLLECTION'} collection #this is still from the changed function above, take that line out for your code
'select `collection` as test'
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.